# Query GROUP BY with max value an date of the value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, max, min

I have to query a table of samples grouping by hour or day and get the result with AVG, Max with the date of the max value and the same with a Min value. The table is going to be huge so I need the best performance.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE Samples (
[Id]                INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[AvgValue]          FLOAT       NULL,
[SampleDate]        DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[MaxValue]          FLOAT NULL,    
[DT_MaxValue]       DATETIME NULL,
[MinValue]          FLOAT     NULL,
[DT_MinValue]       DATETIME      NULL
);
```

Rows in table:

```
Id  AvgValue    SampleDate          MaxValue    DT_MaxValue         MinValue    DT_MinValue
1   10          2018-01-01T01:00:00 15          2018-01-01T01:02:00 9           2018-01-01T01:08:00
2   15          2018-01-01T01:15:00 18          2018-01-01T01:22:00 10          2018-01-01T01:16:00
3   17          2018-01-01T02:15:00 19          2018-01-01T02:27:00 12          2018-01-01T02:17:00
4   20          2018-01-01T02:30:00 23          2018-01-01T02:42:00 14          2018-01-01T02:34:00
5   22          2018-01-01T02:45:00 24          2018-01-01T02:52:00 18          2018-01-01T02:46:00
6   25          2018-01-01T03:00:00 27          2018-01-01T03:14:00 22          2018-01-01T03:01:00
```

Expected result:

```
AvgValue    SampleDate          MaxValue    DT_MaxValue         MinValue    DT_MinValue
12,5        2018-01-01T01:00:00 18          2018-01-01T01:22:00 9           2018-01-01T01:08:00
19,66       2018-01-01T02:00:00 24          2018-01-01T02:52:00 12          2018-01-01T02:17:00
25          2018-01-01T03:00:00 27          2018-01-01T03:14:00 22          2018-01-01T03:01:00
```

The hard part is to get date linked to max and min values. I can't change the table but creating a view is possible.

**Update**

Data comes from a remote system which samples data every few SECONDS and, on intervals of 15min, calculate the Avg, the max value read (with datetime when it was sampled) and the min value (with datetime too) for the interval . "SampleDate" is the datetime when the interval started.

What I want is to query the table and group by longer intervals (hour, day, month), but keeping the max value and it's time, and the min with it's time.

With "group by hour" I mean a want get the values for every hour every date, this is, "2018-01-01T01:00:00" is a different hour from "2018-01-01T01:00:00"

I hope this helps to clear the question

Comment: Why are there three `datetime`s in that table? What is their meaning? The time the value "right" (as seen in the example representation) was gathered? If so, there are there three tables in one -- **normalize** it, ASAP! And what's with the time transformation -- it seems the values of `SampleDate` in your expected result have "lost" their minutes (and seconds, etc.)? But `DT_MaxValue` and `DT_MinValue` are precise to the minute. That doesn't add up. What's the actual expected groups you want here? Please edit this question and clarify what you really have and what you really want.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I added more info to clear the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  To get summaries by day:

```
SELECT CAST(SampleDate as date),
       AVG( AvgValue ) AS AvgValue,
       MAX( Maxvalue ) AS MaxValue,
       MAX( DT_MaxValue ) AS DT_MaxValue
FROM t
GROUP BY CAST(SampleDate as date);
```

The easiest way to get samples by hour is to include the hour as well:

```
SELECT CAST(SampleDate as date), DATEPART(HOUR, SampleDate),
       AVG( AvgValue ) AS AvgValue,
       MAX( Maxvalue ) AS MaxValue,
       MAX( DT_MaxValue ) AS DT_MaxValue
FROM t
GROUP BY CAST(SampleDate as date),  DATEPART(HOUR, SampleDate);
```

Comment: It's not what I need. You get the max date and I need the date of the max value. Pls, see updated info